# How to register lambda expression into Func<>

Tags: c#, reflection, lambda

there is `Register` function below:

```
private Dictionary<string, Func<ResolveContainer, object>> _allocFunctionList = ...;

public void Register<T>(Func<ResolveContainer, object> allocFunction)
{
    string allocFunctionKey = typeof(T).ToString();
    if (_allocFunctionList.ContainsKey(allocFunctionKey))
        throw new AllocFunctionKeyExistsException();

    _allocFunctionList[allocFunctionKey] = allocFunction;
}
```

and use case

```
Register<IFoo>(resolver => new Foo());
Register<IBar>(resolver => new Bar(resolver.Get<IFoo>()));
```

The Lambda Expression have many kind return type.

So declared return type is **object** in

```
Func<ResolveContainer, object>

private Dictionary<string, Func<ResolveContainer, object>> _allocFunctionList = ...;
```

**Question 1**

I need to use reflection with the object in the Register Function
but The Register function knows `Foo`'s interface(`IFoo`) and `Func<..., object>` -> return type

I want to know Foo and Bar's Type in The Register Function.
how to know Lamda Expression's `REAL` return class type without update method definition.

Extract real return type in Lambda Expression with any Lib?
or parse Lambda Expression?

Comment: You can use object.GetType() and compare to typeof(string), typeof(int),....  Or get the string name of the type.

Comment: why you donot just use the allocFunction.Method.ReturnType?

Comment: thx for reply. object.GetType() and allocFunction.Method.ReturnType is just object. I want to know REAL TYPE Foo or Bar